# python: using a list of keyword to be searched on a txt file

Tags: python, search

I'm new to python and im trying to search through a txt file, using keywords from another txt file.
My code looks like this so far:

```
testfile=open('D:\\Coding\\testfile.txt')
keywordfile=open('D:\\Coding\\keyword.txt')

testfile.seek(0,0)
keywordfile.seek(0,0)
for keyword in keywordfile:
    print('\n****************\nlooking for: ', keyword)
    testfile.seek(0,0)
    for line in testfile:
            if keyword in line:
                print('keyword: ', keyword)
                print('line: ', line)
```

The keyword.txt contain the following:

```
quick
fox
jumps
```

And testfile.txt contain the following:

```
the quick 
brown fox jumps 
over the lazy dog
near the river banks
```

It's supposed to find each keyword in tesfile.txt and print it, however when i run above code i have the following results:

```
****************
looking for:  quick


****************
looking for:  fox


****************
looking for:  jumps
keyword:  jumps
line:  brown fox jumps
```

It doesn't find the first two keywords and instead only finds the last one.

I have a feeling this might just be a simple error on my part but i'd really appreciate your help in clarifying where i have got it wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: In every open you need (filename, "r") for reading the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest you to read the files once and save them in memory, so that you don't have to re-read them every time. You can use Python's with statement, so you don't have to close them after processing.

```
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as f:
    testfile = f.readlines()

with open("keywords.txt", "r") as f: 
    keywords = f.readlines()
```

Then, the error in your code is that the rows in a file may contain the newline character `\n` or spaces `' '`. Python has a handy function to solve this problem: `strip()`. Here's the loop code:

```
for keyword in keywords:             
    kw = keyword.strip()     
    print('\n***********\nlooking for: ', kw)
    for line in testfile:
        if kw in line:
            print('keyword: ', kw)
            print('line: ', line)
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the simplicity of your suggestion. Helped a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problems when reading keywords, it may also contain the \n or \t or \r character or space (' ') at the end. How about you use string.replace to eliminate that possibility:

```
 if keyword.replace(' ','').replace('\n','') in line:
```

or you can also use string.strip() in python:

```
if keyword.strip(' \t\n\r') in line:
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought of this from the top of my head

```
lines1 = testfile.readlines()
lines2 = keywordfile.readlineS()

searchList = []

for line in line2:
    lineSplit = line.split(" ")
    for item in lineSplit:
        searchList.append(item)

for item in searchList:
    for line in line1:
        if item in line:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from itertools import cycle

with open('test_file','r') as tf, open('keyword_file', 'r') as kf:
    keywords = [k.strip() for k in kf]
    for lineno, line in enumerate(tf):
        for i, key in enumerate(cycle(keywords)):
            if i==len(keywords):
                break
            if key in line.strip():
                print "Keyword: '"+key+"' found on line: "+str(lineno)
```

Output:

```
Keyword: 'quick' found on line: 0
Keyword: 'fox' found on line: 1
Keyword: 'jumps' found on line: 1
```